# matching a string in ruby with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following line

```
'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6)'.match(//)[0]
```

which obviously doesn't match anything yet

I want to return the just the content of `(2.2.5,` so everything after the open parentheses and before the comma.

How would I do this?

Comment: The important thing when creating regex is to note your binding features. You want to identify the unique characters or words that will always be just before or after the items you wish to identify. In this instance '(' will always be just before, and ',' will always be just after, making the regular expression very simple (as szeryf indicated). The only complication is that '(' is a special character, requiring you to quote it with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beanish solution fails on more than 2 version numbers, you should use something like:

```
>> 'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6, 1.8.6)'.match(/\((.*?),/)[1] # => "2.2.5"
```

Comment: if only . and 0-9 are valid,  you can even get more specific
/\(([\.0-9]*),/

Comment: szeryf, that regex got garbled in formatting, I think.  It's got mismatched parentheses as it appears in my browser: /((.*?),/

Answer (score 1):

```
'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6)'.match(/\((.*),/)[1]
```

if you use the $1 element it is the group that is found within the ( )

Comment: I think you forgot a `/\` 'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6)'.match(/\((.*),/)[0]

Comment: use a tool like http://rubular.com/ 
or http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test your regex online

Comment: this is greedy matching, it will eat everything until _last_ comma, so when there are more than 2 versions it will return all but last.check this out:

>> 'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6, 1.8.6)'.match(/\((.*),/)[1]
=> "2.2.5, 2.0.6"

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

s = 'passenger (2.2.5, 2.0.6)'
p s.scan(/(?:\(|, *)([^,)]*)/).flatten    # => ["2.2.5", "2.0.6"]
```